# How to open SQL Oracle Modeler File?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Im new using Sql Developer data Modeler, I made a Model using this tool but I dont Know how to re-open cause SqlDeveloer has created XML files, The app has created a folder that contains two folders: map and rel, map contains two files:

[image: First Folder]

[image: Rel Folder]

I dont Know what file i have to open from sqldeveloper, to reload the designed model that is a relational model, i dont Know how to reload all table.

I opened every xml file but the model is not loading the tables, what i have to do?

[image: Trying to open sqldeveloper]

[image: What file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution,

I was created New relational model Design,

Looked up for main project File, I copied the main file from the damaged project and change next lines:

```
   <relationalModel class="oracle.dbtools.crest.model.design.relational.RelationalDesign"    name="PreciosModel" id="CF6F32EB-1ADF-A4D4-42E5-1871F2A3D75A" mainViewID="1A7856BA-66B4-D0E8-BF00-0204C3F41BBB">
  <createdBy>Raul Martinez</createdBy>
  <createdTime>2016-02-15 23:01:24 UTC</createdTime>
  <ownerDesignName>Diseño2</ownerDesignName>
  <shouldBeOpen>false</shouldBeOpen>
  <selectedRDBMSSite>32076570-2523-435C-2E92-BF29817DFF70</selectedRDBMSSite>
  </relationalModel>
```

LastOwnerName:preciosModel

NewOwnerNameDiseño2

Again I solved it by my self.